# Vega custom style for text mark

Tags: data-visualization, vega

So as usual I have trouble applying what I read in the Vega documentation. It seems like several parts are missing or I don't know how to read it.

Problem: I have a text mark corresponding to a point in a scatter plot. Imagine one red dot with "Ferrari" written next to it. I want to style the text to be bigger and of a different color.

If I go to the Vega documentation, to the marks section, I see a promising property there: `style` and I read: **Style** -- A string or array of strings indicating the name of custom styles to apply to the mark. A style is a named collection of mark property defaults defined within the configuration. That sounds perfect.

I then went on to create the following in the config object:

```
config': {
      'axis': {
        'labelColor': '#b5bcc8',
        'labelFontSize': 15,
        'labelFont': '(quatro)',
        'titleColor': '#b5bcc8',
        'titleFontSize': 15,
        'titleFont': '(quatro)',
        'titlePadding': 20,
        'tickColor': '#b5bcc8',
        'domainColor': '#b5bcc8'
      },
      'custom': {
        'textFontSize': 22
      }
}
```

Then apply this custom style to the text mark, as suggested:

```
{
   'name': 'product_label',
   'type': 'text',
   'from': { 'data': 'salesData' },
   'style': 'custom',
   'encode': {
      'enter': {
         'x': { 'scale': 'x', 'field': 'month', 'offset': 8 },
         'y': { 'scale': 'y', 'field': 'salesTotal', 'offset': -5 },
            'text': { 'field': 'name' },
            'fill': { 'value': 'black' }
        }
      }
  }
```

Of course, I made a lot of assumptions here, as I have no examples for this. I assumed *named collection* means an object. I assumed *textFontSize* is a valid object property for Vega. But these assumptions may as well be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as usual, it has been proven that I don't know how to read the documentation. So the style configuration is right under the config section:

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/config/#style

Basically, what I did is that I created this custom style following in the documentation example:

```
'style': {
   'custom': {
     'fontSize': 16
    }
 }
```

... and then applied it to my text mark, as in the example above.